Decomposition of Spectrum of $U^{-1}TU$, where $U$ is unitary and $T$ selfadjoint
Suppose we have two Hilbert spaces $H_1,H_2$ and a densely defined self-adjoint operator $T:H_2\supseteq D(T)\to H_2$ as well as an unitary operator $U:H_1\to H_2$. Define $S:=U^{-1}TU:U^{-1}D(T)\to H_1$.
Now clearly, since $U$ is an isomorphism $\sigma_p(T)=\sigma_p(S)$, where $\sigma_p(\cdot)$ denotes the point spectrum of an operator.
Question:
Can we also conclude that $\sigma_c(T)=\sigma_c(S)$ and $\sigma_r(T)=\sigma_r(S)$, where $\sigma_c(\cdot)$ is the continuous and $\sigma_r(\cdot)$ the residual spectrum?
Idea:
I am currently thinking the claim is correct, my line of reasoning being:

$U$ is an isomorphism, thus $U^{-1}\text{ran}(T-\lambda\text{id})=\text{ran}(S-\lambda\text{id})$
and therefore, since $U$ is an isometry, we obtain: $\text{ran}(S-\lambda\text{id})$ is dense iff $\text{ran}(T-\lambda\text{id})$ is dense.

Is this the correct idea and could someone provide me with a rigorous proof? Thanks in advance :)

Yes, this is all correct. For what it’s worth, I don’t believe a rigorous proof is needed. A unitary operator is an isomorphism between Hilbert spaces, so it might as well be the same space with the vectors renamed. Of course renaming vectors are not going to affect the spectrum in any way.
